# nodejs - mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated

Tags: express, mongoose

I research many page and i also receive almost advice is add mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; before connection.
This is my code:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean', function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Connected to DB');
    }
});
```

The first time program run ok. Data is added to database. But, in the second time, I still get error :

```
DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

Any help me this problem ?

Comment: This is probably related to this [Github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4951). The same thing is happening to me when using Mongoose 4.8.x. The error does not appear when using 4.7.9.

Comment: Why are you loading `var mongo = require('mongodb');` When you're using `mongoose`

Comment: Thanks Random User ! I removed it.

Answer (score -1):

This is a warning saying that Mongoose's default promise library is deprecated.

You should use third party promise libraries instead e.g. Bluebird or Q.

Here's an example of using Bluebird promise and promisifying Mongoose using that:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Promise from "bluebird";

// promisify mongoose
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose);
```

Now, you can use Mongoose as promises and it will not give you the deprecated warning.

Comment: He has already replaced the native mongoose library with the node one.